# How to get the HP ALM data from particular date using Talend RESTClient

Tags: java, rest, talend, rest-client

I'm using Talend OS for ESB 6.3.0 and tried to get the data from HP ALM. It is working fine. Now  trying to pull the data from ALM, if the data is greater than particular date.
My Job:

```
tMongoDBConnection --> tRESTClient --> tExtractXMLFiled --> tXMLMap -->tMongoDBOutput
```

In **MongoDBConnection**, I've configured my server,db and port.
In **RESTClient**, basic settings --> URL & Advanced settings --> cookie values.
In **ExtractXMLFiled**, gave Loop XPath Query & Mapping details.
In **XMLMap**, Mapping with the corresponding columns.
In **MongoDBOutput**, storing the data.
The above mentioned way only I've pulled the data from hp alm, but i need to pull the data from particular date.
even i tried in `tRESTClient ->Basic settings -> Query parameters` gave the name & value like, **"particularDate"** as name ,
**"{last-modified[>= (2016-01-01 00:00:00)]}"** as value.
But still its pulling all the data from alm.
Note: last-modified is one of the column name in HP ALM & am using in my job also.

How can i get the HP ALM data from particular date using RESTClient? How can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do following tasks.

```
1) First check that we have to pass last-modified column as parameter or header in HP ALM REST API Documentation.
2) Could please try with REST clients like POST man or other tools.
```

Thanks,
A Ravi Kumar,

Comment: how to pass the date column as a parameter in rest client url. I've tried like "context.last-modified" HP ALM url, but it didn't take the value.